# Different resolution support android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-xml, android-drawable, screen-resolution

**Edited Question:**

**Mobile Resolution:**
 I would like to design different screen dpi like following resolutions. 

320x480,
480×800,
540x960,
720x1280 (Samsung S3),
1080x1920 (S4, Nexus5,Nexus 5x, Moto G4),
2560 x 1440 (Nexus 6, Nexus 6p, Samsung edge)
**Tablet Resolution:**
 480x800 (micromax) ,
600x1024 (samsung tab2),
800x1280 (nexus 7),
1200x1920 (new nexus 7),
2048x1536 (nexus 9)

I want to use **different font sizes** depending on the device display resolution.

Q1) What is the `best` way to solve this `problem`?

Q2) What is best option doing throw coding or XML?

Q3) Which drawable folder is represent which device resolution?

Q4) Application Launcher icon size for different resolution?

Comment: Screen resolution does not matter. Screen density matters.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO answer][1] and make a try on your code.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: Please stop bumping your question with trivial edits. If this continues, we'll lock the question.

Comment: @Sotti: Screen sizes != screen resolutions.

Comment: @Sotti: If you read my comment, you will notice that I wrote that screen resolution does not matter. I did not write that screen size does not matter.

Answer (score 194):

**App launcher icon size in pixels for different resolution**

Mobile Resolution

- mipmap-mdpi (48X48)
- mipmap-hdpi (72X72)
- mipmap-xhdpi (96X96)
- mipmap-xxhdpi (144X144)
- mipmap-xxxhdpi (192X192)

---

### Tablet Layouts:

Use following folders if you wish to have tablet-specific layouts:

```
layout-large-mdpi   (1024x600)
layout-large-tvdpi  (800x1280)
layout-large-xhdpi  (1200x1920)
layout-xlarge-mdpi  (1280x800)
layout-xlarge-xhdpi (2560x1600)
```

### Drawables folders:

1. Mobile

   ```
   res/drawable        (default)
   res/drawable-ldpi/  (240x320 and nearer resolution)
   res/drawable-mdpi/  (320x480 and nearer resolution)
   res/drawable-hdpi/  (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
   res/drawable-xhdpi/  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD etc)
   res/drawable-xxhdpi/ (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, Nexus 5, etc)
   res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (1440X2560 - Nexus 6,Samsung S6edge).
   ```
2. Tablet Resolution:
   [image]

   ### Font Sizes:

> **NOTE:** Always try to use SP whenever you deal with `textSize`, like `textsize=12sp`

1. Use predefined `textAppearance`:

   It will set text size automatically as per device density.

   ```
   <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
   <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
   <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   ```

   Sample usage:

   ```
   <TextView
       style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
       android:text="Sample Text - Small" />
   <TextView
       style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
       android:text="Sample Text  - Medium" />
   <TextView
       style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
       android:text="Sample Text  - Large" />
   ```
2. Use `dimension.xml` for each device:

   From **Google IO Pdf**, we see structure below:

   1. Mobile:

      ```
      res/values/dimens.xml(default)
      res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
      res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
      res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
      res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc)
      res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
      ```

      > res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml (1440X2560 - Nexus 6,Samsung S6edge).
   2. Tablet:

      For tablet you can use more specific folder like `values-xlarge`, `values-large`.

      ```
      res/values-large/dimens.xml      (480x800)
      res/values-large-mdpi/dimens.xml (600x1024)
      ```

      or

      ```
      res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml      (600x1024)
      res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml      (800x1280)
      res/values-xlarge-xhdpi/dimens.xml (2560x1600 - Nexus 10")
      res/values-large-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (1200x1920 - Nexus 7"(latest))
      ```

> **For further information:**
>
> 1. Refer to [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
> 2. See Page# 77 of **Google IO Pdf** for Design [device density](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/designing_and_implementing_android_uis_for_phones_and_tablets.pdf). In that, you will find the way to handle `dimens.xml` for different different devices.
> 3. Getting Your Apps Ready for [Nexus 6 and Nexus 9](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html).

### Excerpt from [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a **"medium"** density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen
>   pixels is simple: `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`. For example, on a 240 dpi
>   screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp
>   units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of
>   your UI on screens with different densities.

Comment: So theres is really no need to implement any code? just create the dimensions and the app will automatically check which dim to apply?

Comment: Yes its one of the way throw which we can create application compatible with all devices.

Comment: always try to prefer textAppearance

Comment: for tablet layout please check this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Comment: +1 : Don't forget that you can support all devices by using layouts.

Comment: I downloaded google Nexsus 10 - 4.4.2 2560*1600 Genymotion, when I run my layout on virtual device,it use layout-sw720dp instead of layout-xlarge-xhdpi ! why? :-?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian For Tablet: 
1024X600   (layout-large-mdpi)
800X1280   (layout-large-tvdpi)
1200X1920 (layout-large-xhdpi)
1280X800   (layout-xlarge-mdpi)
2560X1600 (layout-xlarge-xhdpi) please check in device rather than simulator.

Comment: please also check this below link may be its help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151121/android-supporting-all-tablets-categorize-drawables-and-layouts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: @BhaveshJethani ok for example Nexus 6 will fall into this res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ with graphic 1440X2560 pixels. Then in photoshop which resolution to use? I must use 500 ppi? Because Nexus 6 has 493 ppi density

Comment: @BhaveshJethani I have some confusion regrading xxhdpi launcher icon size. you said for xxhdpi app icon should be 144x144 but as per the android developer guidelines  they wrote for extra-extra-high-density app icon should be 180x180  with android developer guidelines. Please suggest me where is gap

Comment: @Ajit 144X144 for more detail you can take check this link http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: @BhaveshJethani    why there is no mipmap-ldpi?

Comment: @shreyansjain now a days no one going to give support to very small devices :p ... but still you can use it

Comment: this line is what i'm looking for res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml (1440X2560 - Nexus 6,Samsung S6edge).

Answer (score 25):

First you create the different values folders for different screens.and put the size according to the screens
in `res->values->dimens.xml` file and call the simple font size using `"@dimen/text_size"`.

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml

//for small    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">15sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for normal    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for large    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">30sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for xlarge    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">40sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and retrieve the font size in `TextView` as given below.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: so how u have given the dimensions here for diff layouts?like u used any ratios (1:1.5:2:3:4)-(mdpi-hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi:xxxhdpi)-(2sp:3sp:4sp:6sp:8sp) like this?I am confused..!

Comment: @AsifSb if you going to give it by ratio you have to set it programatically.Otherwise you have to put dimentions in static way in different diemens.xml in value folders

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the problems of different screen resolutions and different densities, I size and position everything based on the percentage width and height of the screen. If text is resized based on the percentage width or height of the screen, the font will be the correct size on all devices and all resolutions. To get the correct font size based on a width and height of its space, simply use this function:

```
private float SetTextSize(String text, int width, int height)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
    float textSize = (int) ((width / textWidth) * paint.getTextSize());
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);

    textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
    textSize = (int) ((width / textWidth) * paint.getTextSize());

    // Re-measure with font size near our desired result
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);

    // Check height constraints
    FontMetricsInt metrics = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
    float textHeight = metrics.descent - metrics.ascent;
    if (textHeight > height)
    {
        textSize = (int) (textSize * (height / textHeight));
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
    return textSize;
}
```

Here's the code to get the width and height of the screen:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
{
    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y; 
}
else
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    screenWidth = display.getWidth(); 
    screenHeight = display.getHeight(); 
}
```

To get the font size you want, simply make up an area based on the screen width and screen height and tweak it until the font size looks right. Once you get it looking right, it should look right on all devices.

```
float textSize = SetTextSize("text", (int) (screenWidth * 0.1), (int) (screenHeight * 0.15));
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Re "*.. percentage width/height of screen*".  NOTE: This strategy is *perfect* for screens with fixed number of items; on a screen that displays a scrolling list of items, for large phones I prefer a compromise between "larger" and "show more rows". A possible formula is to multiply all font sizes by `sqrt(phoneWidthInches / defaultWidthInches)`, where `defaultWidthInches` is the original phone size you design for. So 2x larger phone would be 1.4x larger fonts. (instead use `height` or `diagonal` formula as appropriate). **Important**: **DO NOT USE width in pixels**. `inches = pixels / dpi`.

Answer (score 8):

Basically you need to create a Text Style something like this:

```
<style name="CodeFont">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

read more about it here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

And using the android support for different screens guide to create the different sizes you want for different screens in the right res folders as described in: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Side note: I don't really understand in what situation would you want to do that, using SP units for font sizes will scale the fonts to look more or less the same size on different phones.

Answer (score 4):

First your application design for one resolution .

example : suppose your mobile resolution 380*480

```
       mobile screen width:380

       textView size is 80dp   
       Assume : if width is 380dp then 100 % then

               textview width 80dp then how many %(per).

            ower answer is: 25 %
```

find screen size programmatically   using belove formula

```
    DisplayMetric  displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    ScreenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    ScreenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        txt_height = (int)((ScreenHeight*14.58)/100);
    txt_width = (int)((ScreenWidth*37.5)/100);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams normal_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(txt_height ,txt_width );

    txt_Name.setLayoutParams(normal_param);
```

Comment: i want to give text size .. for different device size.

Comment: @BhaveshJethani calculate textsize percentage using above code ,try it code is work for me .

Comment: i am talking about Font size.. not textview size

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good answer:

[Text size and different android screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes)

But here how you can do it with screen resolution :

You can create "values" resource directory for each resolution like

```
values-wWIDTHp-hHEIGHTdp (you can also use values-wWIDTHp or values-hHEIGHTdp)
for example: 320*480 will be values-w320p-h480dp
```

In each dir (including default values dir) create a file named "dimens.xml" with content:

```
 for exmaple (the value related to the resolution):
 <dimen name="def_font_size">10sp</dimen>
```

Now you can use the "@dimen/def_font_size"
or create a style in the default values directory.

Add this to the "styles.xml":

```
<style name="FontSize">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/def_font_size</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function which convert size of dp to the size according to screen size and it is working well for me. Any one having problem with text size according to screen should give this a try.

```
public float convertFromDp(int input) {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return ((input - 0.5f) / scale);
}
```

simple give the value given by it to the text view size programically as below

```
tvTextView1.setTextSize(convertFromDp(24));
```

Comment: this answer working for me. reduce work load  & calculation

Answer (score 1):

For nexus 6 device support , create drawable-560dpi folder and put all images in it.

Comment: I think its not necessary and good to make a particular layout like that, However drawable-xxxhdpi will be even more easier and helpful

Comment: it will not for nexus 6 . Because nexus 6 having 560dpi resolution. If you are not declaring 560dpi folder , than it will use images of xxxhdpi folder.

Comment: Yes to make it simple and not pin point nexus 6 alone I suggested that. images will not differ that much so xxxhdpi is easier.