# Android images to scale properly in different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm new to Android and I'd like to know why those images I put in <kbd>hdpi</kbd>, <kbd>ldpi</kbd>, <kbd>mdpi</kbd>, <kbd>xhdpi</kbd>folders are not actually responding to what I want.

In <kbd>hdpi</kbd>, I put images that are fit for big screens.

In <kbd>ldpi</kbd>, for small screens, in <kbd>mdpi</kbd> for normal screens and for <kbd>xhdpi</kbd> for tablets.

But I wonder why it's still not displaying the correct images for big screens. It looks like small images (that are fit for small screens) on the screen. I have named the images exactly the same. What is wrong with this?

I need your suggestion. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find some help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices/16910589#16910589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't have the problem in the code, nor in the images, but in the **devices** you're using to try the different densities. If you are assuming that larger screens means higher densities, that is not always the case. Note that `hdpi`, `ldpi`, `mdpi` and `xhdpi` refer to **density**, not screen size.

For example, below you can find two screenshots of the same `ImageView` pointing to the same `@drawable/a` icon but deployed in two devices with different **screen density**. To make the point I have placed completely different icons (both with the same name `a.png`) in each density folder so that the difference can be easily appreciated:

**2.7" - ldpi**[image: 2.7" - ldpi] **3.7" - hdpi**[image: 3.7" - hdpi]

Comment: So I need to create two different images for different screen sizes?

Comment: Yes, it's recommended for a better user experience, but it's not mandatory. If you don't have, or cannot generate, different files with the same image but with different sizes, then you can put a single image file in the `/drawable` folder and the app will automatically scale it up or down according to your UI design.

Comment: Note that the `/drawable` folder (without any `-Xdpi` modifier) may not be automatically generated when you create your Android Project. So you can go ahead and create it by yourself and place the default image in it.