# how to get correct fontsize from photoshop to android

Tags: android, fonts, photoshop

i know there are lot of questions and answers on font size topic but none of them helps. I have design of my app in photoshop, designed as it should be on mdpi, and i can scale all resources and images just fine for all resolution. What i have problem with is font size and different resolutions.

In photoshop I have font desingned to be 15px on mdpi, how do i calculate it to look the same on all displays. I know i have to specify font size for every pixel density or something but how to get correct value if i have base one 15px on mdpi?

Do i use  ratio 1,5x 2x 3x and just multiply base size or there is different way?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay its the very first answer to this question, download the PDf mentioned, the dimens files and screen/res folders solution

[read first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/give-font-size-according-to-device-densities)

Comment: click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910589/6035305) for direct link to Answer ;).