# using sw720 instead of hdpi values on Nexus 7 800*1280

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I read this link :

[Different resolution support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device)

> res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml (800*1280)

but when I run my layout on Nexus 7 - API 19 800*1280 on the Genymotion,it use

> values-hdpi

instead of

> values-sw720dp

!

[image]

my min api is 14.

why?

Comment: Using density qualifiers for anything other than drawables is unlikely to give you good results. If you use any units other than `px` in your `dimens.xml` resources, the units will already take density into account.

Comment: tnx,'Using density qualifiers for anything other than drawables is unlikely to give you good results.' so, what is the best qualifier name for Nexsus 10 - 4.4.2 2560*1600 device? it use layout-sw720dp instead of layout-xlarge-xhdpi! if I want to use sw<n>dp qualifier for this screen resolution (2560*1600),which should I choose? or What should I choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the Nexus 7 does not have a smallest width value >= 720dp. The Nexus 7 is TVDPI (1.3x) density, so that means the 1280x800 resolution is effectively 961dp x 600dp. So it should match the `sw600dp` qualifier, but it will not match `sw720dp`, as its smallest width is 600dp.

Comment: but when I change values-hdpi on Nexus 7 800*1280, my layout will change ! another question, what is qualifier name for Nexus 7 API 18 - 1200*1920 ?

Comment: If you look at the table [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) you'll see that the `sw` qualifiers take precedence over density qualifiers (e.g. `hdpi`), so if you use `sw600dp`, that will be the directory that the Nexus 7 pulls from.