# Font size issue in Nexus 5 and Samsung s 5

Tags: android, xml

I have **values-xxhdpi** folder having dimens.xml file, i set the font size **34sp** in nexus 5. When I put this on the samsung s5 the font looks very small. Is there any possible way of having the font size look the same (size wise) on both devices?

> android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_34sp"

I have find screen size difference
**Nexus5 4.9"
S5 5.1"**

Provide me generic solution, if possible I want to be able to do this in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method at run time (onCreate) to get the screen dimensions then based on that re-size the font dynamically.

As different phones have the same DPI but different screen dimensions.

Please also view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device)

Comment: I have checked this link but same problem i want to do from xml

Comment: That is not possible from XML because you want to get dimensions and base the font size on that.

Surely a simple method would be easy and hassle free? why do you need it in XML?