# Values folder for samsung note 3?

Tags: android

I am developing app for phone.While creating layout design.I put the size of the image from dimens in value folder.My issue is design is perfect in s3 and moto-g but not in samsung neo note 3 all the three of them are  taking values from xhdpi.Is there any way to giving separate dimens value for Samsung Note 3?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem isn't in the dimens folder.

Your problem is in layout definition. Try to use relative layout to optimize the layout ratio.

You can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) how to use it.

Comment: My issue is I am giving values from dimens for "layout_marginTop".Values given for moto g and s3 is correct.Since density of Samsung note 3 is higher than other two.Its need higher value for margintop.So is it possible to create separate values folder for Samsung note 3

Comment: And you use relative layout?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device

Comment: you try this solution? it helps u?

Comment: you try this solution? it helps u?

Comment: -Thanks ,I optimized RelativeLayout which fixed my issue.