# How do I can design only a layout for all screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I read android documentation about layout designing. But yet I have a question about layout designing. How do I can design only a layout for all screens size? I want have multiple buttons in my application and but when I test my application in my android device that is Three-inch, as a result , one of buttons can not be seen. My application is not advanced and it has only multiple buttons for a few operations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device resolution specification for values/font folder and images/drawable folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/device-resolution-specification-for-values-font-folder-and-images-drawable-folde)

Comment: try not to hard code the button position.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links. This will clear up all your confusions,

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

and Finally,

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)