# How to accommodate to all the screen resolutions android

Tags: android, android-studio, image-resizing, screen-size

I am testing my application on a 540x960 resolution phone and the application works fine, but when I test the device on other resolution phones in my emulator the image animations do not work at all. So my question is how can I make other image resources of my already made images to accommodate for all of the android screen sizes.

Comment: follow below answer that will explain you in detail. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16910589/3713967](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16910589/3713967)

Comment: You will definitely get you all queries resolved here.http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

There is full and well explained tutorial at [Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
Also, you have plugins in Android Studio to create images for all the screen sizes, for example `IconPackDrawable Importer`.

Also you can do this online using [AssetStudio for Android](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)