# dimension folder for different screen sizes

Tags: android, dimensions

I have created `w720dp` dimension folder for supporting tablet screen sizes. It is working for `2048x1536` screen size, but views of layout of `2560x1800` look smaller compared to previous screen size.What dimension folder should I create for `2560x1080` screen sizes?

Comment: do not use `w` folder always use `sw`  , else your layouts will go wild if phone is rotated .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/different-resolution-support-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248

Comment: Redman..What is the difference between sw and w