# View Clipped with resolution 1080 X 1920 phones

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project have custom view has fixed width.The width is specified in values->dimen

```
<dimen name="layout_width">75dp</dimen>
```

The issue is that in some device(eg:Pixel) with resolution 1080 X 1920 this view is Clipped. However some other devices(eg:Pixel2) with same 
resolution everything works fine.

Have tried using different dimension files as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668434/dimension-folder-for-different-screen-sizes) .Both these device are picking from same dimen files

Code

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            tools:background="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your XML

Comment: Where are you using `<dimen name="layout_width">75dp</dimen>` value?

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title android:layout_width= @dimen/ayout_width

Comment: post some screenshot with expected result and actual result

Comment: You mentioned `width=75dp`. As I can see in your code it's the width of your TextView, not image. Please attach some screenshots from your pixel/pixel2 to understand what's the difference and what's cropping there

Comment: Cn you put a screenshot of the same and also you are not using the dimen resource in your layout. Try using the same. Also, does the text looks bigger in the device in which it is clipping?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your imageView, experiment with different scaleTypes to see if any fit your use case.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:background="@drawable/icon" />
```

Other acceptable `scaleType` values are  `FIT_XY`, `FIT_START`, `FIT_CENTER`, `FIT_END`, `CENTER`, `CENTER_CROP`

Comment: It works only for ImageView. I think @Nikhil was asking for a solution which works for different types of Views.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to different screen dpi of devices.
like normal 1080*1960 devices v/s nexus 5x (which has higher dpi with same resolution)

Another example can be of Samsung galaxy edge S6 (it has much higher dpi as 577dpi with xxxhdpi resolutions).

The most consistent and reliable solution would be **not to use static height width**, instead arrange layouts in such a way **using wrap_content and match_parent** properties and relative layouts

Comment: As mentioned in question, phones were Pixel and Pixel2: [compare phones](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=8346&idPhone2=8733). Both have the same ppi and resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~441 ppi density)

Comment: can you post required layout screen shot here