# How to set 4 RelativeLayout Horizontally and Adjust automatically according to screen size

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

[image]

Please Refer to screen shot.
Now my Problem is 
i have make a xml design that is like in screenshot.
i have 4 relative layout contains imageview and textview.
now i want to set these 4 relative layout horizontally with equal space from right,left,start,end.
In my layout when it go on big screen the start and end showing extra space,i know i have set it like that.
But Is there any solution to set these RLs automatic adjust there size according to screen size.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/one"
    android:id="@+id/RL_MainCat"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RL_UploadPres"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/upload_pres_icon"
    android:id="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload\nPrescription"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#1f222d"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_UploadPres"
        android:id="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/find_pharma_icon"
            android:id="@+id/icon_findphar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Find \n  Pharmacy  "
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#1f222d"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findphar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy"
        android:id="@+id/RL_BuyOTC"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/otc_icon"
            android:id="@+id/icon_findotc"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  Buy \n      OTC     "
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#1f222d"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findotc"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RL_BuyMedicine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_BuyOTC"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/medicine_icon"
            android:id="@+id/icon_findmedi"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  Buy \n Medicines  "
            android:textColor="#1f222d"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findmedi"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please add your xml file here.

Comment: have you read [android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for screen size support and for simpler [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917077/5308778) please visit

Comment: @Kishor please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RL_MainCat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/one"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL_UploadPres"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Upload\nPrescription"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#1f222d"
                android:textSize="11sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_UploadPres">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_findphar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findphar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text=" Find \n  Pharmacy  "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#1f222d"
                android:textSize="11sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL_BuyOTC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_findotc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findotc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="  Buy \n      OTC     "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#1f222d"
                android:textSize="11sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL_BuyMedicine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_BuyOTC">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_findmedi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findmedi"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="  Buy \n Medicines  "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#1f222d"
                android:textSize="11sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Below Output**

[image]

Comment: Happy to help you. Happy Weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative layouts inside a Linear Layout having horizontal Orientation with Weightsum 4 or 1. and give each relative layout a weight of 1 or .25

Inside Relative layout width is set to 0dp so that the Layout will divide the Width equally when the weight is added

Use [Scalable SP (ssp)](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) and [Scalable DP (sdp)](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) instead of sp and dp so that the Dimenssions will be adjusted automatically too

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/one"
android:id="@+id/RL_MainCat"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_weight="0.25"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/RL_UploadPres"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/upload_pres_icon"
android:id="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload\nPrescription"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#1f222d"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon_uploadpres"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_UploadPres"
    android:id="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/find_pharma_icon"
        android:id="@+id/icon_findphar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Find \n  Pharmacy  "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#1f222d"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findphar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_FindPharmacy"
    android:id="@+id/RL_BuyOTC"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/otc_icon"
        android:id="@+id/icon_findotc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="  Buy \n      OTC     "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#1f222d"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findotc"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RL_BuyMedicine"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_BuyOTC"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/medicine_icon"
        android:id="@+id/icon_findmedi"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="  Buy \n Medicines  "
        android:textColor="#1f222d"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_findmedi"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```