# Resizing images for different screen sizes

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I need to display an image in an Android app.
I have created images of given sizes:

```
Density DPI Example     Device  Scale Pixels
ldpi    120 Galaxy Y    0.75x   1dp = 37,5px
mdpi    160 Galaxy Tab  1.0x    1dp = 50px
hdpi    240 Galaxy S II 1.5x    1dp = 75px
xhdpi   320 Nexus 4     2.0x    1dp = 100px
xxhdpi  480 Nexus 5     3.0x    1dp = 150px
xxxhdpi 640 Nexus 6     4.0x    1dp = 200px
```

Next, I have made appropriate drawable folders:

[image: Android studio: drawable folders for each screen-size]

And use it in my ImageView in  such a way:

[image: Android studio: Usage of image in ImageView element]

My pictures appear in the smallest version no matter what screen size I check. I have cleaned and rebuilt project, but it didn't change anything. Where have I made a mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running on emulator or actual devices??

Comment: Emulator, may this be the reason?

Comment: I suspect that may be the reason, try on actual device if possible

Comment: I will, but still, I am able to test it only on 2 screen sizes or so, so I was hoping it would be possible to do it using emulator.

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil I have checked it on real device and it also shows the smallest possible image

Comment: Then take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/q/16706076/8587776

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil I did, thanks! I also created completely new blank project and used Final Android Resizer to place those images again and unfortunately it is still not working - still showing image for ldpi size no matter what the actual size is