# How to make Multi screens supported layout for 16:9, 18.5:9, 19:9

Tags: android, layout, multiscreen

I have just developed an android app. The home page of this app have to scroll in 16:9 ratio (1080x1920 pixels)supported devices (including admob bottom banner). But it works pretty well in 19:9 ratio (1080x2280 pixels) and  18.5:9 ratio (1080x2220 pixels) supported devices.
See the below screenshots:

**16:9 ratio (1080x1920 pixels), Samsung S6 edge+**
[image]

**19:9 ratio (1080x2280 pixels), OnePlus 6**
[image]

How to make multi screens supported layout for 16:9(1080x1920), 18.5:9(1080x2220) and 19:9(1080x2280).
[App link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tofabd.batteryanalyzer)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your app properly designed for all possible screens you need to make use of Android resources, specifically dimens and layout folder.

You can add specific resource files for dimensions and layout for different device resolutions/type. The way you can do that is, inside your `res` folder you will find a `values` folder where you store your dimens.xml and a `layout` folder where you store your XML.

You can add values for multiple resolutions by cloning the values folder and renaming it adding `-hdpi`, `-mdpi`, `-xhdpi`, etc

By doing that, the dimens inside those folders will point to the specified resolution, `xhdpi` for example.

You can do the same with layout folder and create specific XML for tablet and phone.

You can check the specifications of each type per resolution in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/different-resolution-support-android/16917077).